# grafana not showing in kubernetes heapster

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, heapster

I have tried to install heapster with grafana and influxdb on my kubernetes cluster. I cannot manage to see the page of grafana, it only shows me `alert.title`.

I think that I did everything right, all the logs seems good, but this is the last problem: If someone will be kind enough to show me what's happening I would be grateful.

Here is a pick of my log for:

```
2016/06/23 13:31:23 [I] Completed 172.17.77.1 - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found 2929 bytes in 1224us
2016/06/23 13:31:30 [I] Completed 172.17.77.1 - "GET /grafana HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found 2929 bytes in 1154us
2016/06/23 13:31:30 [I] Completed 172.17.77.1 - "GET /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/monitoring-grafana/public/app/app.ca0ab6f9.js HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found 23 bytes in 545us
2016/06/23 13:31:30 [I] Completed 172.17.77.1 - "GET /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/monitoring-grafana/public/css/grafana.dark.min.a95b3754.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found 23 bytes in 786us
2016/06/23 13:31:40 [I] Completed 172.17.77.1 - "GET /monitoring-grafana HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found 2929 bytes in 1409us
2016/06/23 13:31:40 [I] Completed 172.17.77.1 - "GET /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/monitoring-grafana/public/app/app.ca0ab6f9.js HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found 23 bytes in 879us
2016/06/23 13:31:40 [I] Completed 172.17.77.1 - "GET /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/monitoring-grafana/public/css/grafana.dark.min.a95b3754.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found 23 bytes in 1349us
2016/06/23 13:31:46 [I] Completed 172.17.77.1 - "GET /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/monitoring-grafana/public/app/app.ca0ab6f9.js HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found 23 bytes in 837us
2016/06/23 13:31:46 [I] Completed 172.17.77.1 - "GET /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/services/monitoring-grafana/public/css/grafana.dark.min.a95b3754.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found 23 bytes in 1181us
```

Update :
Ok I found something in the influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml I changed value : /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/ to value: /

I dont know if it's a good solution but it's working.

Comment: It might be this [GH issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/issues/657). Which version of Kubernetes and Heapster are you using?

Comment: Hello, I use kubernetes 1.2.0 and the heapster in this link [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster)[link] , I will look at the GH issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I commented on the [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/issues/657) to suggest reopen it since you've seen it in kubernetes v1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, my cluster was flawed. I had to install flannel on the master too. With the option --iface=eth1 because of vagrant.

I followed this guide http://severalnines.com/blog/installing-kubernetes-cluster-minions-centos7-manage-pods-services but they didnt say to install flannel on the master.

You can remove NodePort from influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml and you can also put the value : api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/ back.

Now everything is working.